# Integrating Flutter Downloader plugin into AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I am trying to integrate this flutter plugin https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_downloader into my flutter iOs project. The readme section explains how to integrate into AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m, but I only have AppDelegate.swift on my project.

How to integrate the plugin into My Project?

[xcode project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2v1D.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind. it is automatically configured. (no need to do anything).
I just haven't handle the file opening after the file is downloaded since iOS don't have file explorer like android.

(Update) recently the readme is updated with swift section, it works but still need to add **import flutter_downloader**